# Can I link to an external .md file and have it render as text in html?

Tags: html, git, github, markdown, github-pages

I have a bunch of text-based projects I work on in markdown on github in various repos. I've also got a github page, which I'd like to use to showcase some of these projects. What I'd like to do is just link to the current raw markdown files in their various repos (available at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/...), and have it appear as text on my github page.

Basically I want something that works like an `<img>` tag, but instead of displaying an image, it displays the linked markdown file as text (ideally, with formatting). That way I don't have to copy/paste it over each time I update the master.

Using github pages, though, means that I can't install anything onto the server (I think) - the solution just needs to work with html as-is (I think). Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

**If you only have access to the html, the best way to do it would probably be through a javascript markdown parser.**

Your best bet is probably going to be [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked) (though there are numerous others such as [markdown-js](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js), [showdownjs](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown) and [remarkable](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/remarkable) but they're not as widely used).

As for rendering in the style of a tag, the marked documentation shows that you can use it in the browser like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Marked in the browser</title>
  <script src="lib/marked.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML =
      marked('# Marked in browser\n\nRendered by **marked**.');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Which means that you could implement a solution along the lines of:

1. Include your own tag or class with the markdown file to load
2. Once the DOM has loaded, use javascript to [search for that tag or class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)
3. Load the markdown asynchronously and run it through `marked` to parse it to html
4. Replace the contents of the original tag with the rendered html

Hopefully this should be enough to point you in the right direction!